# Tensor with an Exact Sequence of Free Module Still Exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Let $F\rightarrow G\rightarrow H$ be an exact sequence of free $R$-modules and $M$ be any $R$-module.

Is that true that $F\otimes_RM\rightarrow G\otimes_RM\rightarrow H\otimes_RM$ is exact?

If the answer is no, does that hold when all the modules above are finitely generated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$. Then
$$0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\times2}\mathbb{Z}$$
is an exact sequence of free $R$-modules, but the tensor product with $M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is not exact.

Comment: Thank you. That's a good counterexample.

Comment: I actually meet this in the following assumption: Let $\mathcal K_*$ be the Koszul Complex $\wedge^{n+1-i}V\otimes \mathcal O(-n-1+i)$ over $\mathbb P^n$ which is locally free and exact. Let $\mathcal F$ be any coherent sheaf. Then the author claims $K_*\otimes \mathcal F(m+1)$ is exact as well because terms of $K_*$ is locally free. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @Hydrogen In your question, you were only asking about a sequence that was exact at one place. If you have a bounded complex of free modules that is exact *everywhere*, then it is contractible, and tensoring with anything will preserve exactness. Exactness of a complex of sheaves on $\mathbb{P}^n$ is determined locally, so that should generalize to an exact complex of locally free sheaves, I think.

Comment: What's the definition of 'contracible'? Is there any reference for this property?

Comment: Does that mean this: If $0\rightarrow F_*\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence locally free quasicoherent sheaves and $\mathcal G$ is any coherent sheaf, then their tensor is exact. But I still have no idea how to prove this.

Comment: @Hydrogen A chain complex is contractible if it is chain homotopy equivalent to the zero complex. Applying any additive functor to a contractible complex gives a contractible (and therefore exact) complex. Most introductory texts on homological algebra will cover this.

Comment: Why a bounded complex of free modules that is exact everywhere must be contractible?

Comment: @Hydrogen See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1706583), for example.